# How do I get rid of this phantom element in my button

Tags: html, css, button

[The phantom whitespace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xpDad.png)

```
<button onClick={onDropdownClick} className="menu-trigger">
    <img
        className="google-profile-photo"
        src={currentUser.photoURL}
        alt="User Avatar"
    />
    <span>
        <ArrowDown />
    </span>
</button>
```

I want the img tag and the span to be next to each other with no space in between. I cannot get rid of this whitespace in the middle. Does anyone know how?

```
.menu-trigger {
    display: flex;
    width:auto;
    min-height: 5rem;
    position: relative;
    background: white;
    border-radius: 0.3rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 4px 6px;
    box-shadow: 8px 16px 5rem #eeeeee;
    vertical-align: middle;
    transition: box-shadow 0.4s ease;
    margin-top: 1rem;
    border: none;
}

.google-profile-photo {
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin: 2%;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Isn't that just your `flex` space-between?

Comment: When i remove that, it adds the whitespace to the end of the button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to give the image element `flex: 1` so it can fill up that space. Here's a somewhat minimized example...

```css
.menu-trigger {
    display: flex;
    min-height: 3rem;
    position: relative;
    background: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 4px 6px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: auto;
}

.google-profile-photo {
    margin: 2%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    flex: 1;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<button class="menu-trigger">
    <img
        class="google-profile-photo"
        src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACAAAAAgAgMAAAAOFJJnAAAADFBMVEXU3ej///8AAAATExOMrozEAAAAdElEQVR4XpXPsQ2DMBRF0StX4D1c4IYRmAJkeQKPwRL0NJGQp6OK0hG9L5wqRXKbf6RXfX4qrvhDCDtDXoVCWBAS4SlML8KlaTyJDa4K/9QZHPhqQT+r5Rt8g/tgu8FDyMAgJMBrK9zbLsRttneg5gMLu603mI0q2s7nekMAAAAASUVORK5CYII="
        alt="User Avatar"
    />
    <span>
        &darr;
    </span>
</button>
```

Comment: YES thank you so much this has completely solved it. I never knew about this property.

Comment: You'll want to read through https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ :)

Comment: Thank you. That was very useful. Never knew that flex was shorthand for flex-grow, flex-shrink, and flex-basis combined.

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
justify-content: center;
```

and this for your second question :

```
background-size: cover
```

Comment: Thank you, this is kind of fixed it. Now the whitespace is split between both sides of the button.

Comment: @CharlieGroves the second question is answered in the second part.......